# Execute shell command and get log nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, dns, fork

I am using this native nodejs method to run an executable file:

```
child = exec('node app.js',
function (error, stdout, stderr) {}
});
```

The callback is invoked when the process terminates. but i need what the process logs in the console during is lifetime. is this possible? thank you!

Comment: Did you try reading from `stdout` and `stderr`?

Comment: yes but this callback is invoked when process terminates! i need what the application logs when it's started, or some way to passe this data

Comment: Oh. Use `child_process.spawn` instead, and handle the `exit` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead. Example:

```
var cproc = require("child_process");

proc = cproc.spawn("ping", ["www.google.com"]);

proc.stdout.on("data", function(res) { 
        console.log("Data received: " + res);
});
```

Comment: thank you. how is this data passed? is it a stream? how can i take data as object? @Salem

Comment: Yes, i think so. What do you mean by "take data as object"? `data` is just a string of text...